# Use Android Studio to code for an old platform

Tags: android-studio, legacy, android-2.1-eclair

I want to develop an app for an old tablet using API 7 Android Eclair 2.1, but I'm facing problems setting up all the tools needed.

I tried using Android Studio, but when creating a new app, the lowest API I can choose is 14, and when I change it via code, it complains about the libraries being not compatible.

I also tried importing some samples, but it tries to download some old version of `gradle` and apparently the link is down.

I recall that prior to Android Studio, one would use Eclipse, but it seems that it is no longer available.

Is it possible to set up a development environment, or am I better to code from scratch and compile it myself?